# strange urldecode dilemma

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am passing variables to another page with this urlencoded string

```
http://localhost:8888/proseat/index.php/configure/ve/Honda/Civic+%28sedan%29/2007
```

and when I use urldecode to get back the variables everything seems fine. I am using codeigniter here, so after printing out the decoded variables I see the following:

```
Honda
Civic (sedan)
2007
```

When I pass the variables off to be used for sql I get nothing back. The weird thing is if I pass the string "Civic (sedan)" everything works fine.

First I am encoding the url:

```
function fr ()
{
    if ( isset($_POST) )
    {
        $make              = (urlencode($this->input->post('make')));
        $model              = (urlencode($this->input->post('model'))); 
        $year              = (urlencode($this->input->post('year')));   


        redirect('configure/ve/'.$make. '/' . $model. '/' .$year);


    }       
}
```

Then, I decode and pass off to another function for processing.

```
function ve ($make, $model, $year) 
{
    if ( isset($make,$model,$year) )
    {

        $data['make']               = trim(urldecode($make));   
        $data['model']              = trim(urldecode($model));  
        $data['year']               = trim(urldecode($year));   

        $data['makes']              = $this->model_cars->getAllMakes(); //get all the years makes and models
        $data['models']             = $this->model_cars->getAllModels($data['make']);
        $data['years']              = $this->model_cars->getAllYears($data['make'], $data['model']);

        $this->load->view($this->session->userdata('language').'/includes/view_header',$tags);
        $this->load->view($this->session->userdata('language').'/configure/view_configure',$data);
        $this->load->view($this->session->userdata('language').'/includes/view_footer');

    }
    else
        //stuff 
}
```

A dump of the variables:

```
        echo var_dump($data['make']).'<br>';
        echo var_dump($data['model']).'<br>';
        echo var_dump($data['year']).'<br>';
```

This is the result from that

```
string(5) "Honda" 
string(21) "Civic (sedan)" 
string(4) "2007"
```

Finally, this is the function that returns NULL for some reason.

```
function getAllYears ($make, $model) 
{  
    $result = NULL;
    $sql = "select distinct year from seatcover_listings where make=? and model=? order by year desc";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array(($make), ($model)));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) $result = $query->result_array();  //the format of the returned var will be $somevar['name']
    return $result;
}
```

I know the function works fine because if I Use the following line everything works fine:

```
$this->model_cars->getAllYears($data['make'], 'Civic (sedan)');
```

I tried using htmlspecialchars_decode before after using urldecode but still nothing. I can't beleive how much time I have spent trying to figure this out. Please help me out here.

Here is the result to var_dump($sql, $query);

```
string(88) "select distinct year from seatcover_listings where make=? and model=? order by year desc" object(CI_DB_mysqli_result)#22 (8) { ["conn_id"]=> object(mysqli)#15 (17) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["client_info"]=> string(6) "5.1.44" ["client_version"]=> int(50144) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["host_info"]=> string(25) "Localhost via UNIX socket" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(6) "5.1.44" ["server_version"]=> int(50144) ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(270) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) } ["result_id"]=> object(mysqli_result)#26 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) } ["result_array"]=> array(0) { } ["result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["custom_result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["current_row"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["row_data"]=> NULL }
```

Comment: You code-example given is incomplete as it's not visible into which function actually the redirect results. Next to that you should provide debug out, e.g. do the variables that you expect to have values actually already contain the values you expect? What does `var_dump($make, $model, $year);` output before you urldecode them?

Comment: Then please do a `var_dump($sql, $query);` as well after you've fired the sql query in your broken function.

Comment: The default allowed characters as per `config.php` are `a-z 0-9~%.:_-` your example url `../Civic+%28sedan%29/..` contains a `+`. Perhaps you should try adding that to the allowed chars.

Comment: Yeah, my guess it's the prepared statement. What does the final query actually look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the variables values.  Notice that your 'model' variable is printed as

```
string(21) "Civic (sedan)"
```

however string "Civic (sedan)" contains only 13 characters, therefore it's padded with something else, which makes it 21 chars long.  You need to figure out what that padding is and strip it before using the variable.

Comment: yes that is strage. How can I see what is causing this padding? I have tried using trim but the length is still 21.

Comment: Get the char array from the string and print it one char at a time cast to integer - you'll see the ascii codes of all the characters.

Comment: So it looks like there are extra characters getting added: #40; and #41;  How can i get rid of these since htmlspecialchars_decode and urldecode does not work?

Comment: You could possible use regex to replace anything you don't want with blanks, something like `/[^\w\d() .,~%]/` globally replace with empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving default values to the getAllYears method. Also, I'm not sure if parenthesis around array values are legal or not; beware that result_array() returns the whole result set; looking at your comment in the code it seems either you talk about retrieving a value after a loop, or by using row_array() instead, which returns a single row.

```
function getAllYears ($make = '', $model = '') 
{  
    $result = NULL;

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT year FROM seatcover_listings WHERE make=? and model=? ORDER BY year DESC";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($make,$model));

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        $result = $query->result_array();  //the format of the returned var will be $somevar['name']
    }
    return $result;
}
```

You could also build a conditioned query using AR:

```
$this->db->select('year');
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->from('seatcover_listings');
if($make != '')
{
    $this->db->where('make',$make);
}
if($model != '')
{
    $this->db->where('model',$model);
}
$this->db->order_by('year','DESC');
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();
```